# Как получить бесплатную лицензию JetBrains на ПО с открытым кодом?

Tags: intellij-idea, лицензирование, jetbrains, opensource

Возможно ли получить бесплатную некоммерческую лицензию на `JetBrains IDEA Ultimate Edition` для использования при разработке проекта с открытым исходным кодом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указано на [официальном сайте](https://www.jetbrains.com/community/opensource/), JetBrains поддерживает проекты с открытым исходным кодом бесплатными лицензиями на свои продукты.

Для этого нужно заполнить форму [запроса лицензии с открытым исходным кодом](https://www.jetbrains.com/shop/eform/opensource) и описать свой проект и себя:

- о проекте:

  - Project name
  - Primary language(s)
  - Project age
  - Project website
  - Repository URL
  - Latest release URL
  - License URL
  - Country / region
  - No. of active contributors
  - Project description
- о себе:

  - Name
  - Email address
  - Your role in project