# Как мне использовать лицензию для моего open-source проекта на github?

Tags: github, лицензирование, opensource, авторские-права

Как мне использовать лицензию для моего open-source проекта на github?

- Я могу просто скопировать код лицензии (к примеру MIT), запихнуть в `LICENSE.md` и он будет лицензирован? Это будет так работать?
- Мне нужно указывать своё настоящие имя или ник (псевдоним)?
- Могу ли я лицензировать код если мне нет 18?

Comment: Да, да, неважно, да (с 14 лет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, да, неважно, да (с 14 лет).
*Спасибо adreymal*

Answer (score 4):

Добавляем в корень проекта файл `LICENSE.md`, текст лицензии лучше приводить с переводом: [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) ≈ [Лицензия MIT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_MIT). Сначала оригинал, затем перевод. Выглядеть это может, например, вот так:

> ## Distributed under MIT License
>
> Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
>
> ## Распространяется под лицензией MIT
>
> Copyright (c) <год> <владельцы прав>
>
> Данная лицензия разрешает лицам, получившим копию данного программного обеспечения и сопутствующей документации (в дальнейшем именуемыми «Программное Обеспечение»), безвозмездно использовать Программное Обеспечение без ограничений, включая неограниченное право на использование, копирование, изменение, слияние, публикацию, распространение, сублицензирование и/или продажу копий Программного Обеспечения, а также лицам, которым предоставляется данное Программное Обеспечение, при соблюдении следующих условий:
>
> Указанное выше уведомление об авторском праве и данные условия должны быть включены во все копии или значимые части данного Программного Обеспечения.
>
> ДАННОЕ ПРОГРАММНОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ ПРЕДОСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ «КАК ЕСТЬ», БЕЗ КАКИХ-ЛИБО ГАРАНТИЙ, ЯВНО ВЫРАЖЕННЫХ ИЛИ ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЕМЫХ, ВКЛЮЧАЯ ГАРАНТИИ ТОВАРНОЙ ПРИГОДНОСТИ, СООТВЕТСТВИЯ ПО ЕГО КОНКРЕТНОМУ НАЗНАЧЕНИЮ И ОТСУТСТВИЯ НАРУШЕНИЙ, НО НЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЯСЬ ИМИ. НИ В КАКОМ СЛУЧАЕ АВТОРЫ ИЛИ ПРАВООБЛАДАТЕЛИ НЕ НЕСУТ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТИ ПО КАКИМ-ЛИБО ИСКАМ, ЗА УЩЕРБ ИЛИ ПО ИНЫМ ТРЕБОВАНИЯМ, В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ, ПРИ ДЕЙСТВИИ КОНТРАКТА, ДЕЛИКТЕ ИЛИ ИНОЙ СИТУАЦИИ, ВОЗНИКШИМ ИЗ-ЗА ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ ПРОГРАММНОГО ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЯ ИЛИ ИНЫХ ДЕЙСТВИЙ С ПРОГРАММНЫМ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕМ.

---

<sup>См. [«Как получить бесплатную лицензию JetBrains на ПО с открытым кодом?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/967888/236980)</sup>